# Screen Shot or convert an ArtPro file using Automator

Tags: mac, automator, pdf, screen-capture, automation

I am attempting to turn an ArtPro (.ap) image into a pdf, but I can't find any existing or downloadable actions to do anything other than open a .ap file. Because of this I have resolved to Screen Print the picture, save, then convert, but now I can't find anything that will screen capture the image either D: Please help!!

Comment: I should have made it clearer in the question, I am attempting to do this stuff using **automator** as it is for lots and lots of files

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Grab tool, or just a variery of keyboard shortcuts to screencapture any part of whole screen.  The best place to learn the basics is this entry on our very own Blog http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/taking-screenshots-is-a-snap/

Comment: sorry i didn't make it clearer but I am trying to do this on automator, do you know if there is a way of using that tool or those shortcuts on there?